# Google Maps (api v3) - Loop through mysql query results to geocode and place multiple markers on map

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map on a page of search results that show up to 20 listings.  The 20 listings are pulled from a mysql query and looped on the page.  That part is working fine.

However, the google map (which also geocodes the addresses for me), only shows the first listing.  I'm at a loss how to make it loop through each listing and put them all on the map.

I'm sure it will all easy to follow and understand once I get it working, but I just don't have the chops to get it working from scratch.  Google's developer docs haven't been much help either....

Any help immensely appreciated!!

***************  UPDATE TO QUESTION *****************

The answer provided I couldn't see to get working....the problem was that before the fix, the page showed all the listings, but only mapped 1.  After implementing the answer, the page only shows the first listing and the map doesn't show up at all.

I made a trimmed down A & B version.  This is basically a full paste in of the entire page code:

VERSION 1:  This shows all listings on the page, but only maps the first listing:

```
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_db, $db);
$query_my_query = "SELECT * FROM biz WHERE state = 'MO' and city = 'springfield' order by name asc limit 0,5 ";
$my_query = mysql_query($query_my_query, $db) or die(mysql_error());
$row_my_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($my_query);
$totalRows_my_query = mysql_num_rows($my_query);

$address = $row_my_query['address'];
$city = $row_my_query['city'];
$state = $row_my_query['state'];

?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var geocoder;
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.052234,-118.243685);
    var address = '<?php echo $address.', '.$city.', '.$state; ?>';

    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 14,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map, 
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" >
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
        <div>
                <?php do { // horizontal looper?>
                    <?php echo $row_my_query['name'].' '.$row_my_query['address'].' '.$row_my_query['city'].', '.$row_my_query['state']; ?>
                    <?php echo substr($row_my_query['zip'],0,5); ?><br>
                <?php $row_my_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($my_query);
                } while ($row_my_query); //end horizontal looper ?> 
            </div>
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

HERE IS V2:  This only ends up showing 1 listing on the page and the map doesn't work at all:

```
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_db, $db);
$query_my_query = "SELECT * FROM biz WHERE state = 'MO' and city = 'springfield' order by name asc limit 0,5 ";
$my_query = mysql_query($query_my_query, $db) or die(mysql_error());
$row_my_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($my_query);
$totalRows_my_query = mysql_num_rows($my_query);

$address = $row_my_query['address'];
$city = $row_my_query['city'];
$state = $row_my_query['state'];

?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var geocoder;
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.052234,-118.243685);

        var addresses = [];
        <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($my_query)) { ?>
        addresses.push(<?php echo '"' . $row['address'].', '.$row['city'].', '.$row['state'] . '"'; ?>);
        <?php } ?>


    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 14,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
for(i in addresses) {
    var address = addresses[i];
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map, 
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        } else {
            // alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
  }
</script>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" >
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
        <div>
                <?php do { // horizontal looper?>
                    <?php echo $row_my_query['name'].' '.$row_my_query['address'].' '.$row_my_query['city'].', '.$row_my_query['state']; ?>
                    <?php echo substr($row_my_query['zip'],0,5); ?><br>
                <?php $row_my_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($my_query);
                } while ($row_my_query); //end horizontal looper ?> 
            </div>
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help!!  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to resolve this problem, but I know the answer must be right in front of me somehow.

Thanks as always....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) 
You need a PHP loop to iterate the result set from the query, and then generate a javascript array of addresses.

Replace the line:

```
var address = '<?php echo $address.', '.$city.', '.$state; ?>';
```

with...

```
var addresses = [];
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($my_query)) { ?>
addresses.push(<?php echo '"' . $row['address'].', '.$row['city'].', '.$row['state'] . '"'; ?>);
<?php } ?>
```

2) Wrap a javascript loop around your geocoder.geocode function call, to iterate over the addresses array you just generated.

```
for(i in addresses) {
    var address = addresses[i];
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map, 
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        } else {
            // alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
```

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It's way past bedtime, but I can't wait to try this in the morning.  I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: I tried this solution but just couldn't get it to work.  Instead of showing all the listings and only mapping the first listing, now the page shows only the first listings and the map doesn't show at all.